# Test flat file content and format in Java

Tags: java, unit-testing

I have to send a flat file to an external system. A sample file content is given below:

```
START 20150602
HEADER 100.00USD
PRODUCT TEST1                    50.00USD
PRODUCT TEST2                    50.00USD
FOOTER 002
```

This file should follow the below guidelines:

```
First line - starts with START, then space, then today's date in YYYYMMDD
Header line - starts with HEADER, then space, then total amount of first, second, third etc products with 2 decimal points, then currency
First product - starts with PRODUCT, then space, then product name left aligned with total 25 characters, then amount with 2 decimal points, then currency
More products similar to first product, the number of products is dynamic
Footer - starts with FOOTER, then space, then total number of products with 3 digits
```

This format has been given by the external system vendor in excel.

Can anyone of you suggest a better testing strategy in these case? is there any tools to test the file content and format?

Comment: So your task is to test if the file follows the guidelines? That has nothing to do with unit testing. Also there is no code - what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes I will have to test whether the file generated is following the guidelines. I have already implemented the logic. Now checking how to add test cases for this. I am looking for some tools so that I can reuse that in other places also. I have a number of other file formats also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In situations like this, I prefer to explore my options by starting with a simple approach, based on elementary Java features. Here, each line may be described by a regular expression:

```
START (\d{8})
HEADER (\d+\.\d{2})(\w{3})
PRODUCT (.{25}) (\d+\.\d{2})(\w{3})
FOOTER (\d{3})
```

You may not need the parentheses if you don't need to extract and check the values. OTOH, add a list of strings, providing names for these fields so they can be entered into a Map.

You can add a minimum and maximum repeat count for each line, which will let you write some simple logic to iterate through the lines of the file.

These might be factory method calls where all of the above is defined for a couple of lines:

```
LineDef.create( "HEADER (\\d+\\.\\d{2})(\\w{3})", 1, 1,
                "totalAmount", "totalCurrency" ); 
LineDef.create( "PRODUCT (.{25}) (\\d+\\.\\d{2})(\\w{3})", 1, 999,
               "name", "amount", "currency" );
```